# Regex Allow alphanumeric with specific special characters dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, replace

I have big .txt file which I am reading using `StreamReader` (C# .NET).

My requirement is to replace any of the special characters not in the list to replace with space in entire string (multiple occurrences).

List of special characters allowed is `& / - ' . ) (`.

So far, I have tried this but it is not working the way I want it:

```
aLine = Regex.Replace(aLine, "[^0-9A-Za-z().&'/-]+$", " ");
```

Comment: Always use [regex101](http://regex101.com/) when you're in trouble ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex is doing this:

```
String input = "123abc[]]]]]]456:$def";
String aLine = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9A-Za-z().&'/-]+$", " ");
//=> "123abc[]]]]]]456:$def" 
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ original string (did not replace)
```

Remove the end of string `$` anchor:

```
String input = "123abc[]]]]]]456:$def";
String aLine = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9A-Za-z().&'/-]+", " ");
//=> "123abc 456 def"
```

If you want to leave a space for every instance, remove the quantifier:

```
String input = "123abc[]]]]]]456:$def";
String aLine = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9A-Za-z().&'/-]", " ");
//=> "123abc       456  def"
```

Comment: Thanks for that but what if my input string already have spaces i.e. `code "123a   bc[]]]  ]]]45    6:$def" ` and I want those spaces to as it is and have my output string to be like `code "123a   bc         45    6  def" `

Comment: Add space character or \s to the class

Comment: Nice troubleshooting, +1 :)